# Free multi-axis Android charting library

Tags: android, charts

I'm looking for a free Android charting library for two weeks now.
I read the different threads I found on stackoverflow but I did'nt found what I'm expecting.

So I would like to know if someone know a library that matches my expectations.

As an example, I'd like to draw charts that looks like the one on the following link : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

In advance, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org). The intermediate version currently available includes the combined XY charts support that will help you draw that kind of graphs you need.
Please see a screenshot here, showing what the current version can do: [image]

Regards,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

[Androidplot](http://androidplot.com/) supports this as well.  Take a look at the Dual Axis Labels section of [this doc](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/xyplot.md) as well as the NormedXYSeries section of [this doc](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/advanced_xy_plot.md).

There's also a full source sample [available here](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/demoapp/src/main/java/com/androidplot/demos/DualScaleActivity.java).